# Scaffolding Angular 6 component form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

I am creating a new `Angular 6` data entry project that will have number of pages with different forms for Data Input.

Is there a way to `Scaffold Angular 6 component` in the same manner how `Asp.Net Razor Page` Scaffolds. 
for Ex

```
public class Profiler
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; } //Hidden field
    [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; } //Textbox field with Required attribute
        public string LastName { get; set; } //Textbox field
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; } // Input type="datetime"
        public bool IsActive { get; set; } // Input type="checkbox"
    }
```

We can scaffold a `Razor Page Form` from the above code with bootstrap styles.

Now, I would like to scaffold `Angular 6 component` in same manner but with `Angular Material`.

I am able to design `Angular Material` Form manually for each `property` but I want to Scaffold them, as there are many forms to create.

My `TypeScript` file looks

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName?: string;
  dob: Date;
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

I am using `Asp.Net Core 2.1 Web API`, `Angular 6`, `Angular Material`.

Comment: Check this link from doc https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I want system to generate form based number of properties in a class. Either reactive or Template-driven.

Comment: Not that i know of.